# Replicating 0-5k resistance signal

Tags: signal, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I am trying to essentially replace the accelerator pedal position sensor of an electric car. It's a 0-5k potentiometer type throttle.

I have tried using digital potentiometers - MCP41010, 2 in parallel, and MCP41050, 10 in parallel. In the first case, it worked while the wheel were off the ground, but it doesn't work with the wheels on the ground. The second one works when the wheels are on the ground, depending on the battery voltage, the condition of the ground the vehicle is on, and I suppose a amalgamation of completely random factors. I think the problem is the current, because even 10 of them in parallel can handle only 10mA.

I also tried connecting a 10k potentiometer to a motor. This worked, but it's unreliable and prone going haywire just from the usual jostling around that happens when the vehicle moves.

Are there any other alternatives that I can try? I need a way to either
(a) allow a greater current through while leaving the voltage that would build up across the potentiometer bank for a given resistance unchanged
or
(b) produce a variable resistance in a different way, so that it would allow more current through.

Thank you in advance for your help. I really appreciate it.

EDIT: The accelerator pedal model is [EFP-001](https://www.nocoev.com/product/EFP-001.htm).

EDIT: I realised I should explain how the 10 50k potentiometer bank failed. When the battery is dying or when the vehicle is on rough ground, the motor starts slower. When that happens, the driver ends up putting more current through the pot in the pedal (or the circuit I replace it with). When the current exceeds the limit of the mcp41050, the circuit brakes. The driver detects this and stops, which causes the current to go back up again. This keeps happening at about once a second or so, and the vehicle does not move.

EDIT: More detail on the rest of the components in the system:The motor is a 72V 5kW DC motor. The driver is the Curtis 1205M ([datasheet](https://www.nocoev.com/product/curtis/manual/1204m1205m_n.pdf)). What's installed in the vehicle is [this assemblage](https://www.nocoev.com/product/1205M-6B403_assemblage.htm) which includes the driver, all the other components needed, and the pedal. The wiring diagram of the pedal is given below:
[image: Motor driver wiring diagram, from https://www.nocoev.com/product/1205M-6B403_assemblage.htm]

Comment: You should try to perform some measurements before designing a replacement. For instance, is the accelerator a simple rheostat (2 wires, cursor tied with one end) or a potentiometer (three wires)? What is the current flowing through it? Does it depend on the value of the resistor? What is the voltage at its terminals? All the information you can get may help to diagnose the problem a propose solutions. If you have a schematic of the pedal circuit, then, it will help a lot

Comment: It is a simple rheostat (2 wires). The current flowing through it is 0mA at 0 ohms, but increases with resistance and the load on the motor (I've measured about 20mA). The voltage at the terminals usually goes up to about 3.5V (when the wheels are off the ground).

Comment: It's quite unusual for the current to *increase* with resistance, are you sure it's not the other way around?

Comment: Positive. I've measured the current when the resistance increases (and the drive motor starts to run). When the motor starts up, it draws more current from the pedal for some reason. Then it sort of levels out.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. Otherwise, the question is far too broad. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: My requirements are quite specific, I should think. I've managed to make it work with a potentiometer, so I just need to replicate it with a more reliable circuit. The digital potentiometers I've used so far don't work because they don't let enough current through. I was hoping there was a way increase the current I can send through the circuit while keeping the resistance the same.

Comment: Current through the potentiometer shouldn't be high enough that you need to worry about it.  There should be a pull up or bias resistor in the vehicle somewhere, and it should limit the current.

Comment: Is it possible the controller uses a constant current source, and reads the voltage?  That might be more reliable in a vehicle (electrically noisy environment.)  The voltage might then rise above what your digital potentiometer wants to see.

Comment: Or, maybe the voltage is just too high when the vehicle is operating for real.

Comment: Operating voltage for both parts is 5.5 V.  If you exceed that, it won't work right or might die.

Comment: It definitely reads a voltage, as far as I can tell, but the current is 0 when the resistance is at 0, as is the voltage. I've never caught the voltage going over about 3.5V when the pedal is pressed all the way. I will try measuring both the current and voltage when it's moving, today if possible.
I'm still pretty certain that the problem is current, because the wiper current of both parts is just 1 mA.

Comment: What is the power source for the digipots?  5V or 3.3V?  I would almost bet that you are powering the pots from 3.3V.

Comment: Wait, did you read the datasheet of your controller? At page 10 and following the possible throttle circuits are shown. You can use a type 2 throttle, which is just a voltage source. Just provide the appropriate voltage (0-5V, you can use an ADC or a digipot) to pin J3 (one of the two terminals of the original potentiometer) and you should be fine. Much simpler than your solution. You will lose the possibility to diagnose the throttle from the controller, but without knowing the way it is implemented there is no possibility to implement it

Comment: Yes, the digipots are supplied by a 3.3V supply. I'm running it from a STM32 board, so I use 3.3V to make communication easier.

Comment: I would prefer to implement a type 2 throttle, but I don't have the equipment to change the settings of the controller, and even if I do, I'll be unable to switch it back to manual when I want to, short of installing a completely new pedal, which I don't want to do.

Comment: And there's the problem.  Answer incoming.

Comment: If you edit in the information about the supply voltage, I'll upvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

The digipots' potentiometer pins only accept voltages between the power rails.

You are powering the pots from 3.3V. The inputs to the digipots will be clamped to zero or 3.3V if you exceed the voltages limits.

The motor controller uses a 5V signal for speed control.  Your pots are clamping at 3.3V.

You need to use a 5V power supply for your digipot - one pot should be sufficient.

You might have damaged one or more of the digipots operating them incorrectly.

1. Convert to 5V operation.
2. Use a new (or known good) digipot.
3. Use logic level shifting between the processor and the digipot to deal with the 5V/3.3V digital signal conversion.

---

The datasheets for the pots mention that you cannot connect voltages outside of the power rails to them.

Look for a section labeled "Resistor Terminals" in the table "DC Characteristics."  The line "Voltage Range" says "0 to Vdd."  That's "zero volts to supply voltage."

Maximum supply voltage is 5V for both models of pot that you used.